# jquery responsive on resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

i want to check (on resize) the window width and then load a special part of a script. when the browser window is < 500px width i want to scroll to the top of the div (when clicking on a menu link) and when the browser window is > 500px i want to scroll to the vertical middle of the div when i click on a menu link. it somehow works but it's slow and buggy.

first i create the "resize" function
then i check the browser width

```
(function($){

    // on load
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var current_width = $(window).width(); //check width

            $('.go').click(function (e) {

                if(current_width > 700){ // when min-width 700px than go to center of DIV

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $box = $('.box').eq($(this).data('rel') - 1);

                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $box.offset().top - ($(window).height() - $box.outerHeight(true)) / 2 // scroll to verticall middle of div
                    }, 200);

                }


                else if(current_width < 700){ // when max-width 700px than go to top of DIV

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $box = $('.box').eq($(this).data('rel') - 1);

                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $box.offset().top + 0 // scroll to top of div
                    }, 200);

            }

        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

when id do it with "document ready" everything works fine ... but "document resize" makes problems.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/D6D7E/2/)

update - got it working this way:

```
$(".go").click(function(){

            if ($(window).width() < 800) { // if window smaller than 800px    
                var $box = $('.box').eq($(this).data('rel') - 1);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $box.offset().top - 0
                }, 200);
            }

            if ($(window).width() > 800) { // if window bigger than  800px
                var $box = $('.box').eq($(this).data('rel') - 1);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $box.offset().top - ($(window).height() - $box.outerHeight(true)) / 2
                }, 200);
            }

        });
```

Comment: You keep attaching the event handlers on every resize of the browser.

Comment: yes ... is there another way? onLoad is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to attach the event handlers like this:

```
var resizeTimeout; //the timeout prevents triggering the resize event more than once
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(resize, 500);
    });

    $('.go').click(function (e) {

    });
});

function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 700) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: like this? doesn't work ...

 function resize() {
     if ($(window).width() > 700) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var $box = $('.box').eq($(this).data('rel') - 1);

      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $box.offset().top - ($(window).height() - $box.outerHeight(true)) / 2 // scroll to verticall middle of div
      }, 200);

Comment: @herrfischer The truth is that you don't really need in this case the `$(window).resize()` event handler, only the click handler.

Comment: yes, but i have to check the screenwidth in a responsive way. hmmm, think i implemented it the wrong way? [unhappy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/D6D7E/4/)

Comment: @herrfischer You check the width with this: `$(window).width()`. By the way if you try your code with Firebug enabled yo will see the errors. And in the resize event the `this` is the window.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bad idea but you can try something like this in css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
    $("body").css({"position":"absolute", "top":"12px", "left":"12px"}); //Set your x and y 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    $("body").css({"position":"absolute", "top":"22px", "left":"22px"}); //Set other stuff
}
```

No javascript needed :)

PS: NOT tested!